# Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component in reducer

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo

I am getting the following error in my react native app:

> Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component error

I have gone through several available solutions which are not solving the problem. Please help me to understand what I am doing wrong here.

This is what I have tried in reducer:

```
const Home = (dispatch) => {
  let isUnmount = false;
  return async () => {
    try {
      const response = await Server.get("/user/home");
      if (!isUnmount) {
        if (response.data.flag == true) {
          dispatch({ type: "StoreData", payload: response.data.data });
        } else {
          dispatch({
            type: "addError",
            payLoad: "Something went wrong please try again",
          });
        }
      }
    } catch (error) {
      dispatch({
        type: "addError",
        payLoad: "Something went wrong please try again",
      });
    }finally{
       isUnmount = true;
    }
  };
};
```

Here is useEffect in the component:

```
useEffect(() => {
    let isUnmount = false;
    if (!isUnmount) {
      Home();
    }
    const listner = navigation.addListener("didFocus", () => {
      if (!isUnmount) {
        Home();
      }
    });
    return () => {      
      listner.remove();
      isUnmount = true;
    };
  }, []);
```

Comment: Useeffct won't run till the component is mounted.

Comment: @Asutosh any example code will be helpful

Comment: The API seems incorrect, according to docs addListener return an unsubscribe function where do you get .remove() from? Did you try following the example in their docs it looks cleaner without needing an isMount check? But as far as I can see it's `const unsubscribe = ...` and `unsubscribe()` or simply `return unsubscribe` - https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigation-events/#navigationaddlistener